# Images don't appear in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I'm trying to view images in an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application but it doesn't work.

This is my controller function to add an item with image

```
public IActionResult Add(ProductEditViewModel model, string? returnUrl = null)
{
    string? UploadUrl = "/wwwroot/Uploads/Product/";

    string newFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + model.Image.FileName;
    model.ImageUrl = UploadUrl + newFileName;

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine
            (
                Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                "wwwroot",
               "Uploads", "Product", newFileName
            ), FileMode.Create);

    model.Image.CopyTo(fs);
    fs.Position = 0;

    ProductRepo.Add(model);
    UnitOfWork.Save();

    return RedirectToAction("Get");
}
```

I want to view it in a table, here is my `<td>` in the view:

```
<td> 
    <img src="@V.ImageUrl" style="width:100px; height:100px;">   
</td>
```

`@V` is a `ProductViewModel` type.

What is the problem? I don't even know where to trace.

Comment: Use ‍`wwwroot` only when saving the image to the hard disk, but when displaying the image in your browser, the url should not contain `wwwroot`.

Comment: When you debug,you could press F12 to check the source uri of the image and other errors,you could check the uri then share it with us

Answer (score 2):

When you want to show image saved in `wwwroot` folder, You can't write url like `wwwroot/.../...`, browser will not find this path. You just need to write the project structure  as url without `wwwroot`.

For example, My project structure is as follows：

```
wwwroot
 -css
 -js
 -lib
 -image
  --Test.jpg
```

If I wanna show `Test.jpg` in the page, The correct Url is `<img src="/image/Test.jpg" />` instead of `<img src="/wwwroot/image/Test.jpg" />`.

**Note**: When you want to Serve files outside of web root, You also need to configure the Static File Middleware.